# How to copy or insert dropdownlist to html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

```
function DisplayADSearchResults(result) {
        var table = "<table id='myTable'>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th style='width:20px;'>&nbsp;</th>" +
        "<th style='width:100px;'><b>First Name</b></th>" +
        "<th style='width:100px;'><b>Last Name</b></th>" +
        "<th style='width:200px;'><b>Email</b></th>" +
        "<th style='width:200px;'><b>Login Name</b></th>" +
        "<th style='width:200px;'><b>Role</b></th>" +
        "</tr>";
    for (var counter = 0; counter < result.length; counter++) {
        var chkId = 'chkUserSearch' + counter;
        var fId = 'fUserSearch' + counter;
        var lId = 'lUserSearch' + counter;
        var eId = 'eUserSearch' + counter;
        var unid = 'unUserSearch' + counter;

            var myData = "<tr>" +
            "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" + chkId + "' /></td>" +
            "<td id='" + fId + "' class='searchFirstName'>" + result[counter].FirstName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + lId + "' class='searchLastName'>" + result[counter].LastName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + eId + "' class='searchEmail'>" + result[counter].EmailAddress + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>" + result[counter].LoginName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>" + ddlStaffCategory + "</td>" + //i want do display my "ddlStaffCategory" drop dropdownlist in this column. 
            "</tr>";
        table += myData;
    }
    table += "</table>";}
```

I have the above function that am using to dynamically create an html table from the results of a search. In my razor view, i have a dropdownlist that is already created and populated with values.

Does any one know how i can display that dropdownlist in the last column of my table above for each row?

Below is the dropdownlist source.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlStaffCategory", new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control form-control-dropdown-medium" })
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried @ADyson's suggestion like below (last 2 columns) but that just prints the html as plain text not as an dropdownlist control

```
var searchData = "<tr>" +
            "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" + chkId + "' /></td>" +
            "<td id='" + dId + "' class='searchDomain'>" + userDomain + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + fId + "' class='searchFirstName'>" + result[counter].FirstName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + lId + "' class='searchLastName'>" + result[counter].LastName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + eId + "' class='searchEmail'>" + result[counter].EmailAddress + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>" + result[counter].LoginName + "</td>" +
            "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>" + "@Html.DropDownList(\"ddlStaffCategory\", new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, \"Value\", \"Text\"), new { @class = \"form-control form-control-dropdown-medium\"})" + "</td>" +
            "<td>@Html.DropDownList(\"ddlStaffCategory\", new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, \"Value\", \"Text\"), new { @class = \"form-control form-control-dropdown-medium\"})</td>" +
            "</tr>";
```

Comment: You can simply concatenate the Razor HTMLHelper code into your HTML string. At runtime it'll evaluate the razor statement and output a string of HTML, which will then form part of your table markup when your JS function is executed, as if you had written the HTML manually into the JS function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.DropDownList(...)` just generates something like :

```
<select id="SelectId" name="SelectName">
    <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Opt2">Option2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Put your razor helper inside a `<td></td>` and you should be fine

```
var myData =
    "<tr>" +
    "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" + chkId + "' /></td>" +
    "<td id='" + fId + "' class='searchFirstName'>" + result[counter].FirstName + "</td>" +
    "<td id='" + lId + "' class='searchLastName'>" + result[counter].LastName + "</td>" +
    "<td id='" + eId + "' class='searchEmail'>" + result[counter].EmailAddress + "</td>" +
    "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>" + result[counter].LoginName + "</td>" +
    "<td id='" + unid + "' class='searchUn'>@Html.DropDownList("ddlStaffCategory", new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control form-control-dropdown-medium" })</td>" +
    "</tr>";
```